# Control Arduino relay from Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, arduino, serial-port

I'm trying to make a program in Python. What it does, is send a number to Arduino and Arduino turns on the relay or not. But it doesn't turn on the relay.

Arduino:

```cpp
const int pinLED = 8;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(pinLED, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  digitalWrite(pinLED, HIGH);
  if (Serial.available() > 0)
  {
    char option = Serial.read();
    if (option == '1')
    {
      digitalWrite(pinLED, LOW);

    }
  }
}
```

Python:

```py
import serial, time
arduino = serial.Serial("COM6", 9600)
time.sleep(2)
arduino.write(b'1')
arduino.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

From the code it looks like if you set write on LOW, its immediately overwritten by HIGH by this part of CODE:

```cpp
void loop()
{
  digitalWrite(pinLED, HIGH);
  if (Serial.available() > 0)
  {
....
```

So make new condition with '0' and delete line with `digitalWrite` that writes in every loop:

```cpp
const int pinLED = 8;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(pinLED, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  if (Serial.available() > 0)
  {
    char option = Serial.read();
    if (option == '1')
    {
      digitalWrite(pinLED, LOW);

    }
   if (option == '0')
    {
      digitalWrite(pinLED, HIGH);

    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Suggesting a change, this code does not set the pinLED as high at the start of the code. David might get confused as why the led is not on by default.

Answer (score 0):

On every `loop()` call, you set the pin to HIGH. Even if you set it to LOW, it's immediately set to HIGH on the next `loop()` call.

Move the `digitalWrite(pinLED, HIGH);` call from `loop()` into the `setup()` function.

```cpp
const int pinLED = 8;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(pinLED, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(pinLED, HIGH);
}

void loop()
{
    if (Serial.available() > 0)
    {
        char option = Serial.read();
        if (option == '1')
        {
            digitalWrite(pinLED, LOW);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Building on [the answer that @Marthin gave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54271479),

I am guessing you just want to permanently put off the pin when the signal is sent, in which case you have to use a global variable like so:

```cpp
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(pinLED, OUTPUT);
}
bool pinState=HIGH;
void loop()
{
  digitalWrite(pinLED, pinState);
  if (Serial.available() > 0)
  {
    char option = Serial.read();
    pinState= option == '1'?LOW:pinState;
  }
}
```

If you want to control high and low option for the pin, you just have to make a single line change to the above code as so:

```cpp
pinState= option == '1'?LOW:HIGH;
```